# Add a visualforce tab into console app right-hand side

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console

I am trying to add a custom visualforce page into our console app. However, by adding a visualforce tab, it always displays at the left hand side. It is possible we can open it at the right hand side?

[image]

Above is the screenshot demonstrating my issue. I need the visualforce page (Order form) to be shown at the right side(wider side) instead of the left side.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your ask

Comment: @SantanuBoral Updated my question

Comment: how are you opening visualforce? is that clicking on button or link or onloading the screen?

Comment: @SantanuBoral by using a Visualforce tab

Answer (score 0):

@lance , please go to Apps->your console app name ->edit and then in the section which says Choose console components,select your vf page which you might have already and then "align console components" will let you place your component left or right.please check

[image]